# Reading csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

With the following data, using the code snippet, I am getting the following error. Can you please help me with this. I am a beginner in python.
Data :

```
"Id","Title","Body","Tags"
"Id1","Tit,le1","Body1","Ta,gs1"
"Id","Title","Body","Ta,2gs"
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import csv,sys
if len(sys.argv) <> 3:
print >>sys.stderr, 'Wrong number of arguments. This tool will print first n records from a comma separated CSV file.' 
print >>sys.stderr, 'Usage:' 
print >>sys.stderr, '       python', sys.argv[0], '<file> <number-of-lines>'
sys.exit(1)

fileName = sys.argv[1]
n = int(sys.argv[2])

i = 0 
out = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

ret = []


def read_csv(file_path, has_header = True):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        if has_header: f.readline()
        data = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split("\",\"")
            data.append([x for x in line])
    return data


ret = read_csv(fileName)
target = []
train = []
target = [x[2] for x in ret]
train = [x[1] for x in ret]
```

Error:

```
    target = [x[2] for x in ret]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The created file doesn't have more than two lines?

Comment: Sorry, for the mistake in the data. I have editted the question now. Thanks @PauloBu

Comment: What's the point of [x for x in line]?

Comment: @novieq Are there extra newlines (blank lines) after your data? When it tries to index the line `['']` it gives you this error? Adding an if statement to check for that before appending your data would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `file.readline()` and using the file object as an iterable. Don't do that. Use `next()` instead.

You also should use the `csv.reader()` module to read your data, don't reinvent this wheel. The `csv` module can handle quoted CSV values with delimiters embedded in thevalues much better in any case:

```
import csv

def read_csv(file_path, has_header=True):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        if has_header: next(reader, None)
        return list(reader)
```

Last but not least, you can use `zip()` to transpose rows and columns:

```
ret = read_csv(fileName)
target, train = zip(*ret)[1:3]  # just the 2nd and 3rd columns
```

Here `zip()` will stop at the first row where there are *not* enough columns, at the very least avoiding the exception you see.

If there are columns missing in some of the rows, use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) instead ([`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

ret = read_csv(fileName)
target, train = izip_longest(*ret)[1:3]  # just the 2nd and 3rd columns
```

The default is to replace missing columns with `None`; if you need to use a different value, pass a `fillvalue` argument to `izip_longest()`:

```
target, train = izip_longest(*ret, fillvalue=0)[1:3]  # just the 2nd and 3rd columns
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijin for this. I get the following error :
target, train = zip(*ret)[1:2]
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: @novieq: Your CSV file was empty in that case. With no columns to work with, `zip()` returned an empty list.

Comment: I used `ret = read_csv(fileName)
print(ret[0][2])
print(ret[1][2])
target, train = zip(*ret)[1:2]` and I can see the output. So the csv is parsed correctly. Thanks @Martijn in advance.

Comment: You need to slice with `[1:3]` to get two columns; the end value is not included.

Comment: Are you still seeing any other problems?

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. The input file was huge and there are some formatting issues with the data. Some of the columns are missing in some of the rows. Is there any way to deal with such data ?

Comment: @novieq: Yes, use `itertools.izip_longest()`; added that to the answer.